# Can an app for Android process in the background, when the phone is locked? Built on React Native

Tags: android, react-native, security, triggers, native

Does anyone know if it is possible to build a native Android app on React Native, which would be able to run and process in the background - even if the phone was locked?

If, for example, a Recorder was initiated and the phone locked, could you program in gestures? Eg voice triggers or tapping the volume button to action something?

Many thanks in advance for any advice!

Built an audio recorder app in React Native although it would stop after about 5 minutes.

We want an app which would run in the background listening for triggers (voice or touch) to then action something.

Comment: you are saying you want the app to listen for triggers (voice or touch), how? what the user will touch to trigger? or how the voice will reach your app only ? there is no logic in that

Comment: I am considering using a speech-to-text api or library which would convert the speech to an action. I know this is possible but I'm not sure if the function is activated in the app and the phone went to sleep/locked, if it would continue in the background.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if the app is in React Native or actual Native here, the answer is mostly no.  When the screen is off, it goes into Doze mode-  a power saving mode.  When in Doze apps get very limited processing time-  a window every 15 minutes or so.

The power button definitely wouldn't be doable.  With the screen off, you aren't the foreground app and wouldn't get button notifications, even if you were the foreground screen when it was shut off.  Voice triggers could be possible, if your app was whitelisted from Doze (which can't be done programatically), but realistically isn't going to work well and would kill the battery.  And even if you can it would be FAR easier to do natively, as ReactNative only really works well for UI integrations.  Deeper interactions with the OS require either a lot of native modules and workarounds, or are simply impossible due to the threading model not working.

Comment: Thanks very much, really appreciate it. I'll look into Doze but seems like it's going to be tricky.